# Vagrant: running containers that are created via script

Tags: vagrant

I have a script that creates 15+ docker containers (I don't maintain the script) that I would like to use with Vagrant.

These are created in with a shell script inside a Vagrantfile.

On the first 'vagrant up', all the containers are there and everything works as expected.

If I do a vagrant halt or if I reboot my laptop, the docker images do not start, even though the docker restart policy is always.

Is this a bad use case for vagrant? Is there a way around this behavior?

Comment: Your vagrant hard reboot might help this. However, how to do you exepect local laptop reboot to restart the docker images inside vagrant ?

Comment: The vagrant vbox VM(s) starts at reboot, why not the docker containers within it?

Comment: Okay. If it is your local vagrant, that means this can happen. Your vagrant starts, docker restart policy could be set to always - but remember it is just restart policy which means when a docker container is running and goes down, then it mentions to restart. When your VM comes up, it doesn't have a docker image first running. That is your issue. If you run your container once, then kill the process, it comes up because of the restart policy. The difference here is that your container itself is not running first when your vagrant comes up.

Comment: This might possibly be an issue with the script file which you use to make the containers up while bringing up the Vagrant. This is where a little tweak should be needed.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. It is the script, I'm going to have to write a script to get everything to fix.

Comment: Cool. If you find my answers useful, please don't forget to upvote and mark the solution correct